# TreeView Templating madness

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, c#-4.0

i have a few synchronized instances of a TreeView..

it works pretty well, and i am binding some properties to the ViewModel.

```
<Style x:Key="FlattenedTreeViewItem" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">

    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded}" />
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
```

For one reason or another, i decided to override the Template of TreeViewItem.

this erased property bindings above

All i want to do, is bring back the default selection back to the TreeViewItem, but nothing seems to work. 
I tried using a simple Trigger on IsSelected and setting border/background/foreground.. nothing is showing any changes.

I've googled around, and anything i found so far, was a page of XAML just to set Selected style?? 
Isn't there a simple way to bring it back into the template?

same goes for IsExapnded, 
i have to use this:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpansionStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsHost">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed" />
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

seems excessive, but at least this one works.

With selected, i can't get it to work using simple trigger.. and i can't quite bring the Selected style, and i dont want to bring in some huge ugly chunk of xaml .

here is my full template:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>

            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">

                <StackPanel>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpansionStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsHost">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed" />
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" />
                    <ItemsPresenter Name="ItemsHost" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest (and not so pretty) route: wrap the `StackPanel` with a border and change its background in a `Trigger`.

The XAML:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="Transparent">
            <StackPanel>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpansionStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsHost">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed" />
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" />
                <ItemsPresenter Name="ItemsHost" Visibility="Collapsed" />
            </StackPanel>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="HotPink"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

NOTE: - Change "HotPink" to desired colour

NOTE 2: - For a TreeViewItem functionality, you'd better add a `ToggleButton` that will allow the user to expand\collapse the item. The minimum for it to work (somewhere in the stackPanel):

```
<ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
```

P.S. - wait till you see the template for `TabItem` in Luna theme....

Comment: thanks! i ended up reverse engineering the template using expression blend, and found that i was missing that Border around my content presenter. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Templates are *"huge ugly chunks of XAML"*, that's the reality, nothing you can do about that.

Comment: @SonicSoul: The selection should be there already, you just need to make it visible using some triggers that set the background and foreground of a container to a highlighting color. Just copy that stuff from the default template.

Comment: @SonicSoul, you can find the default templates here: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsamples#themes

Comment: ok.. i finally installed expression blend, reverse engineered a template, and saw what i was missing.. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To clean up your page you might be able to use a global "merged resource dictionary" and stuff your template there.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178.aspx